# Accepts two arrays of integers and return the merged array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to solve this lab question-->

Write a method which accepts two arrays of integers and return the merged array. Make this method so that it can be called in main method without creating object of the class.

Now my solution is this code-->

```
class Merge_array{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int c[];
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int b[]={7,8,9,10,11};
    c=merge(a,b);
    for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
        System.out.println(c[i]+" ");
}

static int[] merge(int a[],int b[])
{
    int[] d=new int[a.length+b.length];
    for(int i=0;i<d.length;i++)
    {
        if(i<a.length)
            d[i]=a[i];
        else
            d[i]=b[i-a.length];
    }
    return d;

    }}
```

I am returning d[] array reference(return d) as my output which is local variable in merge() method. I have confusion, whether this is correct way (although code is working). As i am returning the reference of the array that goes out of scope in main and also i wonder after the execution of merge call the memory of int d[] get destroyed by java garbage collector.

Comment: Nothing will be garbage collected until `main()` completes. The variables in `merge()` (`a`, `b`, `d`, `i`) will go out of scope when the method completes, but the objects they reference aren't cleaned until they are no longer referenced anywhere.

Comment: since the reference of array d has been assigned to c, it will not be garbage collected.

Comment: @shmosel  Thanks for helping. Is there is any java documentation that says that variable do not get collected until they are refrenced

Comment: It would be ludicrous for the JVM to clean an object while you still had a reference to it. How would anything work correctly?

Comment: Thanks everyone for replying

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that when you merge you don't want duplicate records then you can use a set (for example a HashSet) to do that.

Set mergeSet = new HashSet();

```
mergeSet.addAll(firstArray);
mergeSet.addAll(secondArray);
```

and then you can use 
mergeSet.toArray to get a new array that contains all the array items but no duplicates.